# Update is updating ALL records even with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vb.net

So... I don't know what is happening here. I have a variable set that holds the CURRENT customerID and compares to the textbox.text to update just that record...

```
Dim updateStatement As String =
    "UPDATE Customers SET " &
    "Name = """ & txtName.Text & """, " &
    "Address = """ & txtAddress.Text & """, " &
    "City = """ & txtCity.Text & """, " &
    "State = """ & txtState.Text & """, " &
    "ZipCode = """ & txtZipCode.Text & """" &
    "WHERE """ & txtCustomerID.Text & """ = """ & customerID & """"
```

Here's is the entire method code:

```
Private Sub UpdateCustomer()
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = MMABooksDB.GetConnection()
    Dim updateStatement As String =
    "UPDATE Customers SET " &
    "Name = """ & txtName.Text & """, " &
    "Address = """ & txtAddress.Text & """, " &
    "City = """ & txtCity.Text & """, " &
    "State = """ & txtState.Text & """, " &
    "ZipCode = """ & txtZipCode.Text & """" &
    "WHERE """ & txtCustomerID.Text & """ = """ & customerID & """"


    Dim updateCommand As New OleDbCommand(updateStatement, connection)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim oledbCmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection)
        Dim customerID As Integer = customerID
    Catch ex As OleDbException : Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

So whenever I hit accept to update, it updates **ALL** records of the database...

**Edit:**  And yes I am aware that this is "bad programming" when not using parameters, but this is how the instructor wants it done.

Comment: I would pose to the instructor... why are you teaching us bad practices and opening ourselves to SQL-injection...

Comment: You code is susceptible to SQL injection vulnerabilities.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 8):

The problem is here:

```
"WHERE """ & txtCustomerID.Text & """ = """ & customerID & """"
```

Assuming that `customerID` (whatever that variable is) equals the same thing as the ID in the text box, that equates to something like:

```
WHERE "1" = "1"
```

Which, of course, is always true, so all rows match that `WHERE` clause.  You probably meant something like:

```
"WHERE CustomerId = """ & txtCustomerID.Text & """"
```

(where `CustomerId` is the name of your ID column)  It would be much better, though, to use a parameter, since the way you have it could lead to SQL injection attacks.

```
"WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId"
```

Comment: I think it should be "WHERE customerID = """ & txtCustomerID.Text & """... where the actual ID is from the text of the customer the user is working with, but agree with parameterizing the queries... bad instructor to even SUGGEST such building queries.

Comment: @DRapp Oops!  Thanks.  That's what I meant.